# Alfresco: unable to backup alf_data

Tags: backup, alfresco

I am an alfresco 3.3c user with an instance supporting more that 4 million objects. I’m starting having problems with backup, because to backup the alf_data/contentstore folder even in a incremental mode, it takes to long (always need to analyze all those files for changes).
I’ve noticed that alf_data/contentstore is organized internally per years, could I assume that the olders years (2012) are not anymore changed? (if yes, I can just create an exception and remove those dirs from the backup process, obviously with a previous full backup )

Thanks, kind regards.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can assume that no objects will be created (and items are never updated) in old directories within your content store, although items may be removed by the repository's cleanup jobs after being deleted from Alfresco's trash can.

This is the section from `org.alfresco.repo.content.filestore.FileContentStore` which generates a new content URL. You can easily see that it always uses the current date and time.

```
/**
 * Creates a new content URL.  This must be supported by all
 * stores that are compatible with Alfresco.
 * 
 * @return Returns a new and unique content URL
 */
public static String createNewFileStoreUrl()
{
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;  // 0-based
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    // create the URL
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(20);
    sb.append(FileContentStore.STORE_PROTOCOL)
      .append(ContentStore.PROTOCOL_DELIMITER)
      .append(year).append('/')
      .append(month).append('/')
      .append(day).append('/')
      .append(hour).append('/')
      .append(minute).append('/')
      .append(GUID.generate()).append(".bin");
    String newContentUrl = sb.toString();
    // done
    return newContentUrl;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Actually no you can't, because if the file was modified/updated in Alfresco the filesystem path doesn't change. Remember, you can hot-backup the content-store (not the lucene index folder) dir, and it's not necessary to check every single file for consistency. Just launch a shell/batch script executing a copy without check, or use a tool like [xxcopy](http://www.xxcopy.com/). 
(I'm talking about node properties, not the node content)

Comment: Actually when a content item is updated a *new* file is created in the contentstore with the new content. So the path stored in the DB actually *does* change and the newly-created content will be stored with the current date and time.

Comment: Will sorry to disappoint, that's not true, I've just checked it right now. When you update content, the physical path of the node (/contentstore/2013/07/25/9/25/ for example)doesn't change. it affects only if there is versioning active.

Comment: So if there is no versioning in place, I can assume that it will never change?

Comment: @Alch3mi5t no, the path (as seen in the Node Browser, for that node) to the content *does* change when you update the content. This will always happen and the only difference that versioning makes is that when that is turned on, the old content items are not subsequently removed by the reaper jobs that run in the background.

Comment: @WillAbson Sorry I realized we were talking about two different things. I was talking about metadata update. Not the effective content of a file.